# Toggle between two styles on focus

Tags: html, class

I have two pre-defined classes (class-normal and class-on-select). A few li elements are making use of class-normal.
How do I make them use class-on-select only on focus/hover?

Comment: Please post your HTML code and CSS. Edit: You can make use of :hover and :focus on selecctors.

Comment: thanks for the answers, everyone! problem is, it's an existing app. Code reads something like -
<li class="class-normal"> <a>Caption1</a></li>
<li class="class-normal"> <a>Caption2</a></li>
<li class="class-on-select"> <a>Caption3</a></li>

As a result, Caption3 is always "selected". Is it possible to make the caption that is currently selected/on focus make use of the class-on-select style and otherwise the class-normal style?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:hover, :focus` on same class to achieve these effects:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Random li</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
    color:black;
    background:#BFBFBF;
    border:1px solid #000;
    /*css for class-normal*/
}
ul li:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    border:1px solid #000;
    /*css for class-on-select*/
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/600/

Answer (score 0):

```
class-normal:hover , class-normal:focus{ 
   //your styling here
}
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```css
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<p><b><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></b></p>
    <p><b>Note:</b> a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS definition in order to be effective.</p>
    <p><b>Note:</b> a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order to be effective.</p>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tbemymx4/)

Comment: thanks for the answers, everyone! problem is, it's an existing app. Code reads something like -
<li class="class-normal"> <a>Caption1</a></li>
<li class="class-normal"> <a>Caption2</a></li>
<li class="class-on-select"> <a>Caption3</a></li>

As a result, Caption3 is always "selected". Is it possible to make the caption that is currently selected/on focus make use of the class-on-select style and otherwise the class-normal style?